# TypeError: countries is undefined ReactJS covid19 app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, typeerror

I'm making covid19 tracker app following tutorial from JavaScript Mastery and i have problem with **TypeError: countries is undefined,**

problem displayed in browser:

```
 19 | return (
  20 |   <FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
  21 |     <NativeSelect defaultValue="" onChange={(e) => handleCountryChange(e.target.value)}>
> 22 |       <option value="">Global</option>
     | ^  23 |       {countries.map((country, i) => <option key={i} value={country}>{country}</option>)}
  24 |     </NativeSelect>
  25 |   </FormControl>
```

//and below fetchAPI

```
  10 | 
  11 |  useEffect(() => {
  12 |    const fetchAPI = async () => {
> 13 |      setCountries(await fetchCountries());
     | ^  14 |    };
  15 | 
  16 |    fetchAPI();
```

CountryPicker.jsx file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

import { fetchCountries } from '../../api';

import styles from './CountryPicker.module.css';

const Countries = ({ handleCountryChange }) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setCountries(await fetchCountries());
    };

    fetchAPI();
  }, []);

  return (
    <FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
      <NativeSelect defaultValue="" onChange={(e) => handleCountryChange(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="">Global</option>
        {countries.map((country, i) => <option key={i} value={country}>{country}</option>)}
      </NativeSelect>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default Countries;
```

For the rest of the code can be looked at JavaScrip Master git https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_corona_tracker/tree/master/src
I have the same code and still doesn't work also i installed all necessary npm dependencies

Comment: did you try awaiting the api call first then setting? `const result = await fetchCountries()`, then `setCountries(result)`. My guess is that calling `setCountries` runs before the api call finishes.

Comment: When I copied your `fetchCountries` function from Github and used it in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-resonance-nljfn?file=/src/App.js) everything worked fine. Do you get any other warnings? Sometimes there is an error like `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` when working with `async/await`

Comment: Thank you John for your responese, but can you be more specific, I'm new to react ,so what do you mean should i add this line in useEffect(). itsanewabstract- no errors in visual studio only in browser ,which i posted

Comment: Well I pulled down your repo and ran the project without any issues. Not sure how you triggered that bug. What are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: Guys thank you so much i found the problem it was in my api/index.js probelm was The grave accent ( ` ) which is so funy because i used ' ,and everything worked when i replaced it ,

Answer (score 0):

replace line 23 with

```
{(countries.length > 0) &&
      countries.map((country, i) => <option key={i} value={country}>{country}</option>)
}
```